# PHP reflection behaviour

Tags: php, reflection

I am trying to figure out how the reflection class works.

When I reflect a class I expect it to have all methods/properties from it's parents.

For example

```
class A
{
  public function foo();
}

class B extends A
{
  public function bar();
}
```

I expect method 'foo' now also be a part of B. But when reflecting and using the method 'hasMethod' I doesn't have the method 'foo'.

Whats the right way to see if somewhere in the inheritance tree the method is there?

My problem lays within checking for the constructor. Some children don't implement a construct method and I was expecting the construct method to be reflect by inheritance.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: PHP's OOP is not you are expecting to see. It is more precisely pseudo-OOP, keep in mind.

Comment: [It returns `true` for me](http://3v4l.org/HmPKf#v5210).

Comment: did you try with [getConstructor](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getconstructor.php) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it works with [getConstructor()](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getconstructor.php) :

```
class A
{
   public function __construct(){}
   public function foo(){}
}

class B extends A
{
   public function bar(){}
}

$class = new ReflectionClass('B');
$constructor = $class->getConstructor();
var_dump($constructor);

//object(ReflectionMethod)#2 (2) { ["name"]=> string(11) "__construct" ["class"]=> string(1) "A" }
```

Answer (score 0):

Surely you don't have to use reflection? You could just use [`method_exists`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.method-exists.php):

```
$object = new B();
if (method_exists($object, 'foo')) {
    //Do something
}
```